# jQuery, Bootstrap and big list (7000+ items) with search/typeahead

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, postgresql

I know I haven't got any code example, but it's due to the fact that I'm unsure on how to proceed.

I'm building a site with jQuery and Bootstrap, and are going to display a list of around 7000+ items.

I'm using $.getJSON(...) to get the list of items from my PostgreSQL database. This call goes pretty quick.

I would like to create a list which is capable of typeahead search/filter, where elements are displayed corresponding to a user is typing.

I'm not interested in calling my PostgreSQL database more than once - if possible - but would also like to not to kill the browser with DOM elements etc.

What are the best way to proceed, are there any existing components in Bootstrap or...?

Comment: ? But then I'm not getting all the data... I need to be able to search/filter throughout all 7000+ data records, but without calling the database every time - with a typeahead/filter kind of way.

Comment: call data and strong it in web storage and create point to re calling data again if besides your filters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ForerunnerDB would be a good library to use: http://forerunnerdb.com/

It's a client side NoSQL db. You'll be able to insert your data into a `collection` and create a view which can handle auto binding of the data to the DOM. Loading over 7000 DOM elements is a big task, lazy loading is probably the way forward for you; my suggestion would be to display 100 records at a time and when the user is close to the bottom of the list trigger more DOM elements to be rendered:

```
//Take data from a collection, query it to build a view, and link it to the DOM
db.view('dataView')
  .query({
      /*
       * Filter documents in the collection
       * calling db.view('dataView').find() will now only pull records from the 'data' collection which contain a key `verified` that have the value 'true'
       */
      verified: true
  })
  .queryOptions({
      //Apply options 
      //calling db.view('dataView').find() will limit the result to the first hundred records
      $limit: 100
  })
  .from('data')
  .link('#targetElement', 'templateName');
```

To unlink the view again call `db.view('dataView').unlink()`.

When you want to render more records, simply do the following:

```
var query = db.view('dataView').query();
query.$limit += 100;
db.view('dataView').query(query)
```

This will automatically render the next hundred records.

Using a combination of `.query({})` and `.queryOptions({})` will allow you to manipulate the view's data pretty much any way that you want, I've been able to build some complex filtering and searching with ease using this technique.

Comment: Thank you. Very much what I'm looking for.

Comment: Does ForerunnerDB require anything else? I'm getting a can't find variable: require when trying to run the example.

Comment: @MichaelNielsen Hey ya, I'm the developer behind ForerunnerDB - To use ForerunnerDB you need to use one of the distribution build files in the js/dist folder, for instance fdb-all.min.js. If you are still having problems you can post a new stackoverflow question or raise an issue on the ForerunnerDB github issue tracker. If you have followed the instructions for using ForerunnerDB in a browser it will "just work" :)

Comment: @MichaelNielsen Also ForerunnerDB has a plugin called Infinilist which allows you to display huge amounts of rows in a scrollable list whilst only "actually" having a small subset in the DOM. It's similar to the way iOS lists and ionic repeat-collection lists work.  Again, if you need any help you can open an issue on the ForerunnerDB github issue tracker :)

Comment: Yes, I did just follow the doc's and added fdb-all.min.js, but when trying to use it via require('forerunnerdb'), it fails with "can't find variable: require".